# Angular multiple view not getting data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having issues getting a simple nested view to display my data I'm trying to pass to it.

The parent view loads the nested...
Note that if I do {{opc.org.address}} before this, it does spill out the data.

```
<div ui-view="address" addressData="opc.org.address"></div>
```

The address template...
Note if I change to {{opc.org.address.(whatever)}} I can see the data fine.

```
<div class="addressWrapper" ui-view>
<span class="address">{{ addressData.address1 }}</span><br />
<span class="address2" ng-if="addressData.address2">{{ addressData.address2 }}<br />></span>
<span class="city">{{ addressData.city}}</span>,
<span class="state">{{ addressData.state}}</span>&nbsp;
<span class="zip">{{ addressData.postalCode}}</span>
<span class="country" ng-if="addressData.countryCode"><br />{{ addressData.countryCode }}</span>
```

We're running the site via Typescript and ui-router. Here's the portion of the router file that loads the parent and address view.

```
.state('search.orgProfile', {
        url: '/orgs/:externalOrgId',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'app/orgs/org-profile.tmpl.html',
                controller: 'OrgProfileController',
                controllerAs: 'opc',
                resolve: {
                    org: function (orgProfileService: IOrgProfileService, $stateParams: any) {
                        return orgProfileService.getOrgProfile(<string>$stateParams.externalOrgId)
                            .then(function (orgDetails: IOrg) {
                                return orgDetails;
                            });
                    },
                    relationships: function (relationshipsService: IRelationshipsService, org: IOrg) {
                        return relationshipsService.getRelationships(org.id, 0, Constants.PAGE_SIZE)
                            .then(function (relationships: RelationshipModel[]) {
                                return relationships;
                            });
                    },
                    notes: function (notesService: INotesService, org: IOrg) {
                        return notesService.getNotes(Constants.NOTES_TYPE_ORG, org.id)
                            .then(function (theNotes: NoteModel[]) {
                                return theNotes;
                            });
                    }
                }
            },
            'address@search.orgProfile': {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/address/address.tmpl.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

When running the page, I only see ",". So it is running as angular, but its not seeing addressData that I passed in. Am I missing something? Do I need to define addressData somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a controller to the nested view and set the addressData to the orgs address that was resolved in the main view. Took a bit of scope spelunking to find it, but once I plugged it in all was well!

```
            'address@search.orgProfileHome': {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/address/address.tmpl.html',
                controller: function ($scope: any) {
                    $scope.addressData = $scope.$parent.$parent.opc.org.address;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope are inherited betweend inherited state/views.

You should be able to use {{opc.org.address}} in your view's template and $scope.opc in your views controller. It will search for the parent scope. Just be aware to initialize your fields on parent scope. For instance if you don't set the value to null before doing an asynchrnous loading but do it in your view's controller. You will have 2 distinct opc object.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/multiple-named-views

There is nothing suggesting you can pass parameters to views, but i don't think you need to.

Since view are internal to a state just use parent's scope.

EDIT : Following the comment : i suggest to use a directive to represent the addressData in a generic way and be able to bind them to a scope. Views are for different part of a state/ Either they represent totally different data (ex : header/content/footer views) or they are used to represent some data inherited from the scope. So they are strongly bind to the parent's state (if any) and you can't detach them. If you need to detach something and bind it to different state/scope, this is what directive are for.

Comment: Yes, using opc.org.address in the address template works, but I need to use this template for more than 1 view, using different controllers. So I need the template to get the address data passed in from the parent.

Comment: Maybe a better question is, how would I set scope.addressData in the ui-route?

Comment: What i'am saying is you don't need to. But if you really want do : $scope.addressData = $scope.opc.org.address in your OrgProfileController. If you want to separate the bindings between the view and the state try to add a resolve addressData:function($scope){ return $scope.opc.org.address} that you inject it in your view controller controller. you'll just had to change the resolve each time you use that template/ctronller in another state

Comment: I tried to set the $scope.addressData in the controller, but got an error that it couldnt get address of null, since the constructor is run before the promise resolves.
I'm going to try adding an abstract controller to the nested view and see if I can set it that way. Or using a resolve on it like you mentioned.

Comment: I think you should build a directive instead of a view if you want to bind some data to the scope in a generic way. This is what it's made for. For me views are used to represent some internal part of your state that are independant between them. But they are depandant to your state meaning they're bind to the parent's state scope and so to their variable. So you can't pass addressData like this. So : directive or change addressData by opc.org.address in your template.

Comment: I tried the directive route, but the template never compiled as angular code for some reason. I like this way better as it is simpler and requires less to get running since we're using Typescript.

I just got it working, by adding a controller to the nested views' route.
'address@search.orgProfileHome': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/address/address.tmpl.html',
                    controller: function ($scope: any) {
                        $scope.addressData = $scope.$parent.$parent.opc.org.address;
                    }
                }

Comment: As i said you don't need to use $parent just do. $scope.addressData = $scope.opc.org.address;